# How to resolve UnusedPrivateParameter error in grpc(java)?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

**resolve UnusedPrivateParameter error**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

visit https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/3.8.0
If you're working in a maven project then add this to your pom.xml file